# How to Build "Thinking in Java" Example Files to Run in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java

I wanted to learn Java, as recommended by most of the people I downloaded "Thinking in Java" eBook and Source Code Example Lesson files from mindviewinc.com it's download location is this http://www.mindviewinc.com/TIJ4/CodeInstructions.html

These files don't work with Eclipse IDE for some reasons. So we have to build the files using the Build.xml file included in it's source code (Honestly, I do not have any idea what does "build" means here)

I tried building myself but of no use.. It did started building but after reaching some folder it stopped and gave error to install jboss-osgi-installer-1.0.0.jar .. After downloading it, I had no idea what to do with it, so I double clicked it and it asked me the location to install and I installed it in the default location, which was C:\Users\Username/jboss-osgi-1.0.0 and when I tried C:\Program Files\Java******** the installation gave error that "this directory cannot be written, please choose another directory!" but anyway I installed it in the default location and it installed..

and again when I tried to build it, it gave me the same error and asked to Install Jboss....... I'm stuck.. This is happening again and again, wasted many days and didn't even crossed 100 pages of it's pdf because of this reason. It's a good eBook though.

I'm stuck in this from months... Please some one build it and make it like a **project** which could be **easily** and send me the project file, it would be really appreciated as I can not the solution to this anywhere on search engines..

Comment: How did you start in eclipse? What did you do? Did you create a project first?

Comment: Yes I created the project first

Comment: The author of the eBook already stated: "This code is designed to work outside of IDEs. Because packages are not introduced until later chapters, and some of the fancier IDEs like Eclipse require all code to be in packages, if you want to use the code inside those IDEs you will have to make some adjustments"

Comment: The exact error during build with ant is "You must install the Javassist library from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/" - which I did, and that was jboss-osgi-installer-1.0.0.jar which I explained what I did with it.

Comment: You need to add it to your project's build path. But... you shouldn't need that jar to build the examples in the book, so I suspect something else has gone wrong. Also, there's a *reason* for doing it outside of the IDE--it reduces the amount of stuff you have to figure out at once.

Comment: @Dave Newton....... I did what you said. But it didn't work.. :(

Comment: Define "doesn't work". I think you're trying to do too many things at once here: I find it impossible to believe the code examples require an OSGI library as part of the project itself.

Comment: I too find it impossible to believe that a beginner programer should have to go through this trauma before itself..

Comment: it was asking for "Javassist" library file..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok here's what I did to succesfully import the sources found in the "accesss" folder of you code samples:

1. Download the javassist jar as per Bruce's instructions, from here:

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javassist/javassist/3.9.0.GA/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar

1. You must create an Eclipse project for the sources that are used as dependencies for most of the examples, that's the sources in the "net" folder:

   - in eclipse make new java project.
   - select the "net" directory, copy it, then in eclipse select the "src" entry in the project you just made, right click on it and select paste.
   - after eclipse finishes and auto-builds, it will complain about the missing javaassist jar. Right click on the project ->properties->java build path (on the left)->libraries (on the top)-> add external jars... (on the right), browse and select the javassist jar from where you down load it.
   - now the "net" project should be ok in eclipse
2. Now let's create the project for the sources in the "access" folder:

   - create a new java project in eclipse
   - Now, because Bruce structured his classes like crap, we'll have to make the proper structure in eclipse for them. This means:
     a.create a new package called "access"
   - go to where your the access folder is on your drive, open it, select ONLY the folders (cookie2, desser, mypackage), copy them, then return to eclipse, right click on the "access" package u just made and click paste
   - now go back to the access dir on your drive, select ONLY the .java files (all of them, not the dirs), copy them, the back to eclipse, click on the src entry in the access project and click paste.
3. The access project in elcipse will still complain about missing classes form the "net" resouce. Right click on the project in eclipse->properties->java build path->projects (on the top)-> add(on the right)-> check the net project you created earlier-> click ok twice.

Now it should be ok

I hope you got the idea on how dependencies work in eclipse with this example.

For the other parts of you code samples, create separate java projects, add the classes to the proper package (create the packages if Bruce forgot to), and if you are missing external jars, go to http://search.maven.org search and download the jars. Good luck

Comment: hey! You solved my whole problem!! I was pulling my hair, I sat whole day in front of my laptop searching for the solution but didn't got any. Your help is really appreciated. Thanks a billion times my friend. This was my first ever question here. I wish I should have asked this on the very day when I got this problem.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: And yeah Bruce made this examples like S*** ;) I wonder in which jungle he was living in at the time of compilation of this source code.

Comment: Hey glad I could help. Hey, let's not be too harsh on Bruce now, he might fumble up the details, but that book you're reading is great over all, I read it about 4 times. He has a nice fresh way of addressing problems.

Comment: lol! yeah u r ryt. But still I want him to read my comment and remember this before making any new Book and Source Code examples.. That's because the pain I've gone through was just (Censored) :P

Comment: And one more thing.. Is there any way to bring all these folders like "access" and all others in under one single project?? if not, can I still work with it this way without any problems in middle of the book? After knowing about you reading it 4 times, I'm glad that I chose the correct book :) Any other book u suggest? :D

Comment: Well theoretically you can go either way, have all the folders into one big project, or have them each in it's own project. In this case I think the best thing to do is create a separate project for each folder, and then if you have code in one folder linked to code in another folder, just add that 2nd project as a resource to the first  project, like we did with "Access" when it need that other project "net"

Comment: thanks.. I did the same which you just asked me to do yesterday itself. . But now I'm facing with some errors in the projects.. It's unable to "IMPORT" something it seems. I tried searching in google but no use.. here is the thing..

Comment: thanks.. I did the same which you just asked me to do yesterday itself. . But now I'm facing with some errors in the projects.. It's unable to "IMPORT" something it seems. I tried searching in google but no use.. here is the thing, where can I find this: com.sun.mirror.apt, javax.jnlp, nu.xom., And in swt folder its complaining about  "org.eclipse.swt cannot be resolved".. And other some folders are complaining of some functions some variables I don't know why, I wonder if this is error from the Bruce side.

Answer (score 2):

"This code is designed to work outside of IDEs. Because packages are not introduced until later chapters, and some of the fancier IDEs like Eclipse require all code to be in packages, if you want to use the code inside those IDEs you will have to make some adjustments"  - yep, bruce eckel would say that, cause that's the kind of guy he is. He also said there's ONLY checked exceptions in java, and asked for unchecked exeptions to be added as a bonus.

Now, if your sample code has no package, aka it's in the default package, aka when you look in the .java file, right at the top  there's no line saying "package what.ever.bla" then all you have to do is:

-in Eclipse create a new Java se project
- open a windows explorer, go to your .java files, select them and copy them
- then in eclipse, right click the src folder in your project and chose "paste"

The files should be added to a "default" package in your eclipse project, without any error

Comment: I took your advice and followed your instructions, but still I'm getting errors... Can you please check it again? :(

Comment: please post the top 10 lines from a .java file that you're trying to import. Or give us the link to where you've downloaded the code examples from, and I'll try importing them in eclipse, and I'll tell you how that went, k? (just adding this: nevermind, you already posted the link, i'll try it now, be back in 5) :)

Comment: This is the direct download link to download http://www.mindviewinc.com/TIJ4/CodeDownload.php Whether or not you would be able to solve my problem, but still Im thankful to you dat you tried to help me with this :) Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest steps that I find to create a clean Eclipse project for the TIJ4 source code:

1. Download the source code zip from: http://www.mindviewinc.com/TIJ4/CodeInstructions.html, and unzip it to a folder, say 'TIJ4-code';
2. Download the additional libraries as in the previous URL, copy tools.jar from your current JDK's lib directory, and put them into TIJ4-code/lib;
3. Go into the 'TIJ4-code' folder, and run 'python Eclipse.py' (you need python installed on your system). This script adds the missing "package xxx" line to those source java files which don't yet have them, so as to make Eclipse happy. It also generates the Eclipse project files, which doesn't work well for some reason (beyond my limited knowledge on Eclipse), but they aren't needed here;
4. Open Eclipse and create a new empty java project, say with name 'TIJ4', choose JRE version 1.5, and "create separate folders for sources and class files";
5. Copy TIJ4-code/lib directory to your new Eclipse project folder;
6. Right click on the new project and select "Build Path" >> "Configure Build Path", then go to tab "Libraries", "add jars", then select all the jars under your project's lib folder;
7. Go to "File >> import", choose "General >> File System", select the unzipped folder 'TIJ4-code' as your "From directory". Check the root 'TIJ4-code' in the left panel of the import window, Click on "filter types" and select the .java, so that unnecessary files of other extensions, like *.class, *.py, *.xml, etc can be ignored during the import;

The zipped folder is no longer needed after the new Eclipse project is built. I hope you find this instruction helpful, and have fun learning TIJ4.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this code in IDE rather than Eclipse and so on, for example in **Intelij Idea** or any other, the best way is  to compile necessary classes from the  TIJ4 with Ant, but it is not easy for the beginners, although it will be a good practice for you. You should make some changes in build.xml files which exists in every directory of TIJ4.  Why?

- to change version of Java(now we all use Java version higher than 1.5)
- to include javaassist.jar library in the "classpath"
- to put all compiled files in 'bin' directory(by default without adjustments TIJ4 build.xml puts .class files in the same directory with .java files. That is not a good deal.

  ---

#### For example you need to import and use within IDE(I use Intelij Idea) the class named net.mindview.util.Print ( see Chapter 3):

1. download TIJ4 and unzip in any directory you want(for example it would be c:\eckel)

   download and install AntApache (you can find detailed instructions how to do it in Google) The result is -  type in your console ant -version and you should see the answer. So Ant is working.

   download javaassist.jar from http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/  . Unzip to any directory, take out javassist.jar and past it to c:\eckel\net

4.**There is build.xml file** in c:\eckel\net. Now you should make adjustments. Open it with NotePad++ or other editor.

- If you don't have Java 1.5 installed on your PC, so change all 'vesion1.5' to 'vesrion1.8' or other version that you have installed.
- after tag description  put `property name = "classpath" value="./;./javassist.jar"/>
  <property name = "src_util" value="./mindview/util"/> 
  <property name = "src_simple" value="./mindview/simple"/> 
  <property name = "src_atunit" value="./mindview/atunit"/> 
  <property name = "destdir" value="bin"/>`
  Then we make targets that will complile util simple or atunit automatically
- Change tag available `<available
  classname="javassist.bytecode.ClassFile"
  classpath="${classpath}"
  property="javassist"
  />`

  Now classpath of available = property named 'classpath'. Classpath is the path where java compiler looks for .class files because some of your .java files want them by having import statement. There won't be error  message "You must install the Javassist library " any more
- Create targets for compiling util simple and so on See the following link with code
  [Code with targets](https://gist.github.com/muzimka/95d91ab49de05e83dd55)

   You can modify exists targets not to write all the code.
- at the top of build.xml file change default="simple"
- open cmd, then  cd c:\eckel\net , then ant -simple  or just ant   (simple will run as default)

   Please write if you will have some problems. Possibly i forgot mention about something.
- Go to Intellij Idea, press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S
- Press +,
- Library or directories
- choose your c:\eckel\net\bin

  5.now you can use import statement for all classes that exist in net.mindview 

  6.you can make the same with other dirs.

Comment: Thank you. I've been programming for years but importing Bruce's libraries had me stumped.   I'm just revisiting his chapter on Concurrency, and couldn't compile the examples.  In relation to the above, you link to a 'code with targets' source file.  Please don't ever remove this, as it was crucial.  I had to delete line 43 in this file to get ant to compile.  Even though I have Java 1.8 installed, I still received the fail message.  Again Sergey thanks for taking the time out for the above - I'm not an Ant man and you helped greatly.  Plus noone uses Eclipse these days!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to you skip the entire Ant build process, I have converted the project to a Maven project (over JDK8), which you can simply import into your Eclipse workspace.

https://github.com/gauravojha/tij4-maven

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sergey Oliv's example.  In addition, I needed to provide uncompiled javaassist package with all java files in the 'net' folder too.  The .jar wouldn't work by itself.

I must say, this was a lot of work to get going.